# How to update the NGINX timeout setting for a Magento 2 Cloud Docker setup

Tags: docker, nginx, magento, magento2

I am working with Magento 2.4.2 (Adobe Commerce Enterprise Edition) and have a local site set up using the Magento Cloud Docker setup. I would like to change the nginx timeout setting to be long enough to let a page I'm testing run for as long as it needs to but still render the page on the browser in the frontend.

Is there a specific environment variable that I can set in my docker-compose.yml file to accomplish this? I'm not seeing anything that would make this update in the [docker-environment](https://github.com/magento-dockerhub/magento-cloud-docker/blob/master/images/nginx/1.9/bin/docker-environment) or [Dockerfile](https://github.com/magento-dockerhub/magento-cloud-docker/blob/master/images/nginx/1.9/Dockerfile) files. Do I just have to add my own custom lines to either of these files to update the timeout setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use [magento cloud docker development](https://devdocs.magento.com/cloud/docker/docker-development.html), no you can't without overriding the docker image.

if you want to set nginx timeout, you need to override the nginx docker image and include it in `docker-compose.override.yml`. here are the step :

1. copy `vendor/magento/magento-cloud-docker/images/nginx` to `.docker/images/nginx`, i.e like [this](https://github.com/dekiakbar/magento244/tree/master/.docker/images/nginx/1.19)
2. edit `.docker/images/nginx/1.19/etc/nginx.conf` and `.docker/images/nginx/1.19/etc/vhost.conf`
3. create `docker-compose.override.yml` , like [this](https://github.com/dekiakbar/magento244/blob/master/docker-compose.override.yml)
4. and run `docker-compose up --build --force-recreate --no-deps --remove-orphans -d`

check [this link](https://github.com/dekiakbar/magento244) for the full example.

> Note : the `.docker/config.env` file will be overwritten when you run `./vendor/bin/ece-docker 'build:compose'`

Comment: Didn't check the exact commands listed above as per my answer below, but this general approach is correct for a more permanent solution

Answer (score 0):

According to Adobe Commerce support, this isn't possible on their Cloud platform which is very unfortunate

In terms of a local environment for testing, a method which is quicker and hackier than the one presented by Deki above is below:

ssh into your tls docker container
edit the /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf file as per below:

server {
listen 80;
listen 443 ssl;

```
server_name _;

ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/magento.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/magento.key;

**# Add the 3 lines below**
proxy_read_timeout NEW_TIMEOUT_VALUE;
proxy_connect_timeout NEW_TIMEOUT_VALUE;
keepalive_timeout NEW_TIMEOUT_VALUE;

location / {
    proxy_pass http://varnish:80;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_buffer_size 128k;
    proxy_buffers 4 256k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size 256k;
}
```

}